# How __toString works in this example?

Tags: php, get, tostring

So I found this problem:

```
// name1.php
namespace Examples\Names;
class Name {
    public function __toString() {
        return "Laurel";
    }
    public static function get() {
        return "Eminent";
    }
}

// name2.php
namespace Examples;
include "name1.php";
class Name {
    public function __toString() {
        return "James";
    }
    public static function get() {
        return "Cook";
    }
}

echo new Name() . " | " . Names\Name::get();
```

And I would like to understand why this echo `echo new Name() . " | " . Names\Name::get();` take displays `James | Eminent`.
I think that I got it about second second part `Names\Name::get()` that it takes from Examples\Names\Name `Eminent` because it has that get, but what about first part? Why it takes `James` by default?

Also, when I try to remove switch from `Names\Name::get()` to `Names\Name()` just to see if it display __toString from second class - `Cook` it doesn't work and I get this error `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Examples\Names\Name() in C`

Can you help me with that? I really want to understand. Thank you!

Comment: Now I understand. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what about first part

...it uses the class from the `Examples` namespace because it's in the same namespace as the `echo` statement. And it echoes `James` because of the `__toString` - that serves as the default function called behind the scenes by PHP whenever you try to put an object into a string.

> switch from Names\Name::get() to Names\Name()

... it would need to be `new Names\Name()` I think, if you want to instantiate the class.